# Redirect to Thank You Page Based on Form Select Option (Hubspot)

Tags: javascript, forms, hubspot, hubspot-crm

I have this code to create a HubSpot form. I am trying to redirect the user to a different page based on what option is selected in the HubSpot field called `numemployees`.

If the user selects the option of "1-150," the redirect URL should be X.
If the user selects any other option, the redirect URL should be Y.

Here is my code. Portal ID, form ID, and redirect URLs are hidden here (fake info used). I used the "external embed" instructions on [this page](https://www.stephanieogaygarcia.com/hubspot-website-development/redirect-a-hubspot-form-to-a-thank-you-page-based-on-a-form-field) to create this code (I am not well-versed in JS).

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="https://js.hsforms.net/forms/embed/v2.js"></script>
<script>
    hbspt.forms.create({
        region: "na1",
        portalId: "123213213131",
        formId: "123123213213213123123123123121",

        onFormSubmit: function($form) {
            var employeeCount = $form.find('select[name="numemployees"]').val();

            setTimeout( function() {
            if (employeeCount == "1-150" ) {
                window.location.href = "https://www.url1.com";
            }       
            else {
                window.location.href = "https://www.url2.com";
            }      

            }, 500 ); // Waits 1/2 second to redirect.
        }
    });
</script>
```

While testing, I can only get the redirect for the second URL here, even when I have selected "1-150" as the value for numemployees.

I have a page where this form can be tested if need be, just lmk!

Comment: can you ```console.log(employeeCount)``` to see what value is being passed.

Comment: @Innovin Prefacing with I do not know JS well, so I wasn't sure where to place it. First I tried to paste it at the end, outside of the }); but before the closing script tag. When I do this, I get ```Uncaught ReferenceError: employeeCount is not defined```, which if I understand correctly is because the variable only exists inside the function, correct?

When I place the console.log inside the function though, I don't see the value being passed, but is that because the function is only running on the submission of the form? I added the instructions I had followed to my original post!

Comment: can you share where this can be tested?

Answer (score 0):

The answer had less to do with my approach and more to do with the fact that HubSpot wasn't using jQuery. With some help from a co-worker, we changed

`var employeeCount = $form.find('select[name="numemployees"]').val();`

to

`const employeeCount = $form.querySelector('select[name="numemployees"]').value;`

and that fixed the issue.